# Is there a way to surpress Azure WebJob Invocation Logs when using WebJob SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Does anyone know if it is possible to control what information is written to the WebJob Invocation Logs when using the Azure WebJob SDK? I am processing a queue which holds sensitive information that i do not wish to store or be displayed in the logs. Is this possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Cheers, Phil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to exclude certain data from being logged.
You can turn off logging by not setting the following ConnectionString “AzureJobsDashboard”.
I will open an issue for us to see if there is a way we can enable this scenario in the future.